# How to add optional comma support in Rust?

Tags: rust, rust-macros, macro-rules

I started learning macros in Rust. I decided to practice a little and write a simple macro for hashmap.
If call the macro this way, then everything works

```
let hashmap = hashmap!{ 1 => String::from("1"), 2 => String::from("2") };
```

But I wanted to add the ability to support an optional comma at the end.

For example, so that I can call a macro like this

```
let hashmap = hashmap!{ 1 => String::from("1"), };
```

My macro looks like this

```
macro_rules! hashmap {
   ($($key:expr => $val:expr),*) => {
       {
           let mut map = ::std::collections::HashMap::new();
           $(
               map.insert($key, $val);
           )*
           map
       }
   }
}
```

I was trying to add something like `,?` or this `(,)?`, but it doesn't work and outputs an error